# Why does d3_rails gem need <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, d3.js

I am learning D3.js in order to replace Highcharts in my application, so it can be released under GPL license. Here is how I installed it:

1 - I declare the d3_rails gem in the Gemfile

```
gem 'd3_rails'
```

2 - I require d3 in the application.js file

```
//= require d3
```

The call to d3.js methods (from within a RoR partial)  did not work until I add this to the partial:

```
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```

Why do I have to declare this again here?
Thanks for your help.

Comment: Not a rails user, but what do the developer tools tell you?  **Without** the explicit load from `<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>` and just the `require` does the browser attempt to load it?

Comment: With or without the explicit load, I see this in the head of HTML : <pre><code> <script src="/assets/d3.self-850dec129b5f20c85fb8f10f3afae50c6efdfc9981c2952916d4a850bf18afee.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>.</code></pre> But this links to D3.js version 3, and not version 4 as expected. I removed highcharts, but this version of D3 may come from the former install ... and conflict.